# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.money')

Tags: react-native

can someone help me? so I'm trying to pass data from add balance components to home but I keep getting an error saying that the object is undefined. I just wanted to update the current balance which is displayed on the home screen if the user adds balance to their accounts.

```
function Home({ props, navigation }){
        return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
             <Text style={{fontSize:30, paddingVertical:150, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Current Balance: 
               {props.money} </Text>
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress= 
               {()=>navigation.navigate("AddBalance")}>
             <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Add Balance</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress= 
               {()=>navigation.navigate("Withdraw")}>
             <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Withdraw</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress= 
               {()=>navigation.navigate("ViewCode")}>
             <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>View Code To Pay</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Login")}>
             <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Logout</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
         );
         }

     const MyFunction = () => Alert.alert('Amount Added Successfully');
     function AddBalance({ navigation }){
     const[balance, newBalance] = useState(0)
     const[amount, setAmount] = useState()

     function addTogether(){
     const Total = balance + amount;
     newBalance(Total);
     MyFunction();
     }

     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:30, paddingVertical:20, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Add Balance</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputBox} placeholder="Enter Amount" keyboardType={'numeric'} onChangeText={(text) => setAmount(Number.parseInt(text))}></TextInput>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress ={addTogether}>
          <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Continue</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Home")}>
          <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Back</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
        <Home money = {balance}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: how you calling this funtion?

Comment: through stack navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `Home` function's parameters

```js
function Home({ props, navigation }){...} //this
```

**With**

```js
function Home(props){...}
```

Then, you can navigate with that `props` like `props.navigation.navigate`, so also replace `navigation.navigate` with `props.navigation.navigate` everywhere.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Ohh thanks maybe I am getting the error because I put the props parameter inside the {}.